# exported Jar wont run, no errors/warning

Tags: jar, export, executable-jar

I have no idea why, but when i export my java program into a Jar it just wont run. There are no errors when building or running it. When I run the program through eclipse it work perfectly.

Anyone had this problem before or care to take a look?

regards,
Matt

Comment: Are you exporting as a `Runnable JAR` ?

Comment: i tried both, when i double click them nothing happens..

Answer (score 1):

As Shark said, it has to be exported as an Executable JAR file.  Just exporting your project to a JAR is insufficient.

Here's a nice write-up on making Executable JAR files:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file/

If you want to make it from Eclipse, Export as Java | Runnable JAR.

Answer (score 0):

windows 8 installed java 1.6 without the correct paths. I installed jdk 1.8 and it worked.